# How to break a list in multiple columns with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, list, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, how can I have something like this:

```
[ 1 ] [ 4 ]
[ 2 ] [ 5 ]
[ 3 ] [ 6 ]
```

In other words, how to break a list into two equal columns, ordering it vertically, using only one `<ul>`? So I can have, for example, a dynamic number of items?

I could use `column-width` and `column-count` [like this](https://codepen.io/isaacalves/pen/VdORYe), but I was wondering if I can achieve the same effect with [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 27):

There's no way to do it with the Bootstrap "Grid". However, you can use Bootstrap's card-columns and set the `column-count`...

```
  <ul class="list-unstyled card-columns">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
  </ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/suY2Ci62Ji

Comment: Nice to know, though that's basically CSS columns :)

Comment: Could we have an example with ```column-count``` included?

Answer (score 5):

Example with `column-count`:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled card-columns" style="column-count: 2;">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using **flex** as I did:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to achieve that with a single list or wrapper, in your example there are 2 columns.